# 404 error in my product url

Tags: product, url, category-products

In my store I sell hats. Main hat is Cap. When I use category bar I pick Hats-->Cap. Browser goes to `hats/cap.html`
And there is descripcion and other stuff.

But on my homepage I also have all hats (products). When I click on Cap, browser goes to `cap.html` and there is **404 error**.

How can I rewrite product url? When I click on product on my homepage I want to get `hats/cap.html` (because there is the stuff from category)

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about your question.

Comment: I mean how to change product's url.

Comment: When I click on product it goes to 404.. I don't know how to create product's page like [here](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1-3-768x350.png)

Comment: Your Magento version ? and how you display the products in the home page ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use url rewrite from

```
Catalog > URL Rewrite Management
```

P.S. wanted to add a comment only, not enough points :(  (i'm too lazy )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento 1 then, after add product you need to reindex.

Make sure below thing
status
website
stock status